# Theano Win10 & cuDNN?

Tags: theano, keras

I found a great blog post here: http://ankivil.com/installing-keras-theano-and-dependencies-on-windows-10/ The issue is that it doesn't specify linking cuDNN.  I was wondering if anybody knew how to get this to work properly.  Does one simply install cuDNN and magic happens or are there further steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually to linking CuDNN you just need to put 4 files that you've downloaded from https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn.

the directory files you'll get are:

```
cuda
 |-bin
 |-include
 |-lib
```

copy files from those directory to the approppiate path, in my windows 10 system at `C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v7.5/`